# Add class to a div after page direct to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

It's little complicated for me (even to explain) but I try.

I have a footer with couple of specific links which should:

1. direct users to another page
2. and then to specific tab by adding a class "active".

That another page has tabs which works with "active" classes. So if user clicks one of the tab it becomes active (as it gets class "active"). Now I somehow need a solution so if user clicks on a link in footer (no matter the page) it directs to that page and also makes that certain tab active.

E.g I have **tabs "Wood", "Stone", "Sand"** which all gets the same **"active"** class after it has been clicked. Now I have a footer with same links "Wood", "Stone", "Sand". And if user clicks on one of the links in footer (no matter the page) it should be directed to that specific tab.

Basically I can direct user to those tab section as it has id (link-url#id) but can't figure out how to also add class so it becomes active.

I thought this could be done with js or jquery but as I searched for solution it seems it's not possible. I can also use PHP (if it's server side related) but not sure how.

EDIT:

Thanks for guidance! I managed to create one solution. Not sure if it's the best but it works as needed.

1. direct users to another page - just add regular url with id to a link. E.g "mypage.com/pagename#wood
2. And then to specific tab by adding a class "active" - code below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

// if url includes my page name with id
if (window.location.href.indexOf("pagename#wood") > -1) {

   // add class active to div which has id of wood and remove active class from other siblings
  $('#wood').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');

  // add class active to tab content div which has id of wood-content and remove active class from other siblings
  $('#wood-content').addClass("content-active").siblings().removeClass('content-active');
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT possible with classes, because the class in HTML is an attribute that can be same for many tags, and if it works with the class the browser confuse which class you call, so it is a general rule that every browser follow it.
It is possible only with ID, as you said.
you can see [this](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) link for different between ID and CLASS.

Answer (score 0):

For a single web application you can create a function that will triggered every load of the page, something like

```js
function handlerTag () {
  const url = new URL(document.baseURI)
  const hash = url.hash.replace('#', '')
  // add your logic for the 'active' class
}
```

[url API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Answer (score 0):

**you can change as per your logic. or you might have #Key with url find it and add class **

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            $('.side-navbar a').each(function () {
                var currenturl = $(this).attr("href");
                if (currenturl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                    currenturl = currenturl.split('?')[0];
                }
                if (currenturl == window.location.pathname) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
                }
            });
        });        });
```

**HTML**

```
 <nav class="side-navbar box-scroll sidebar-scroll">                   
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                 <li>
                 <a href="/Master">Dashboard</a>
                 </li>
                 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. direct users to another page - just add regular url with id as a link. E.g "mypage.com/pagename#wood
2. And then to specific tab by adding a class "active" - code below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

// if url includes my page name with id
if (window.location.href.indexOf("pagename#wood") > -1) {

   // add class active to div which has id of wood and remove active class from other siblings
  $('#wood').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');

  // add class active to tab content div which has id of wood-content and remove active class from other siblings
  $('#wood-content').addClass("content-active").siblings().removeClass('content-active');
}});
```